# PHP function to preg_replace multi-line conditional comments

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I am trying to write a function in php that will loop through a mySQL database and delete all conditional comments.

The text I want to replace looks like this:

`<!--[if gte mso 9]><xml> <o:OfficeDocumentSettings> <o:AllowPNG /> </o:OfficeDocumentSettings> </xml><![endif]--><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml> <w:WordDocument> <w:View>Normal</w:View> <w:Zoom>0</w:Zoom> <w:TrackMoves /> <w:TrackFormatting /> <w:DoNotShowRevisions /> <w:DoNotPrintRevisions /> <w:DoNotShowMarkup /> <w:DoNotShowComments /> <w:DoNotShowInsertionsAndDeletions /> <w:DoNotShowPropertyChanges /> <w:PunctuationKerning /> <w:ValidateAgainstSchemas /> <w:SaveIfXMLInvalid>false</w:SaveIfXMLInvalid> <w:IgnoreMixedContent>false</w:IgnoreMixedContent> <w:AlwaysShowPlaceholderText>false</w:AlwaysShowPlaceholderText> <w:DoNotPromoteQF /><![endif]-->`

here is my code

```
$content = array('1' => $my_text_with_conditional_quotes)

foreach($content as $id => $v){
    print $v .' <br>';
    $str = addcslashes(preg_replace("/<!(--)?(?=\[)(?:(?!<!\[endif\]\1>).)*<!\[endif\]\1>/s",'',$v));
    print $str . '<br>';
    print $id . '<br>'; 
    exit; 
}
```

it's not matching anything.  What am i missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enclose your regex with single quotes `'`

```
'/<!(--)?(?=\[)(?:(?!<!\[endif\]\1>).)*<!\[endif\]\1>/s'
```

or double escape the `\` to reference the capture group

```
"/<!(--)?(?=\[)(?:(?!<!\[endif\]\\1>).)*<!\[endif\]\\1>/s"
```

Answer (score 0):

Move your wildcard period from here: `1>).)*` to here: `1>)).*`

Also, [RegexPal](http://www.regexpal.com/) is awesome for testing your regexes out live, to see what they match.

Comment: Well good idea, but this didn't change the result.  Thanks for the response nevertheless.

Answer (score 0):

don't use regular expressions to parse xml.
You can solve this by using php string functions. It will be something like this:

```
while (1==1) {

    $openingTagOffset = strpos($field, "<!--[if gte mso 9]>");
    if ($openingTagOffset === false) break;
    $closingTag = "<![endif]-->";
    $closingTagOffset = strpos($field, $closingTag, $openingTagOffset);
    $field = substr_replace($field, "", $openingTagOffset, $closingTagOffset - $openingTagOffset + strlen($closingTag));

}
```

Comment: Thanks,I like a good thought.  This will help me solve other problems more efficiently (I think regex uses more system resources); however, I wasn't sure what the start tag and end tag would be exactly, and as far as I know regex is the way to do pattern matching.